# [Prometheus][Grafana] Use label to map metrics between them

Tags: label, grafana, prometheus, exporter

I'm trying to concatenate some metrics based on a parent label value in grafana.

I'm export some metrics for hypervisor like below :

```
vmware_host_num_cpu{cluster_name="cluster1",dc_name="datacenter1",host_name="node1"} 4.0

vmware_host_num_cpu{cluster_name="cluster1",dc_name="datacenter1",host_name="node2"} 2.0

vmware_host_num_cpu{cluster_name="cluster2",dc_name="datacenter1",host_name="node3"} 8.0

vmware_host_num_cpu{cluster_name="cluster3",dc_name="datacenter2",host_name="node4"} 2.0
```

In my example node1 and node2 are in the cluster1, node3 in the cluster2 and node4 in the cluster3.
I have also some specifics metrics for cluster :

```
vmware_cluster_currentFailoverLevel{cluster_name="cluster1",dc_name="datacenter1",region="region1"} 1.0

vmware_cluster_currentFailoverLevel{cluster_name="cluster2",dc_name="datacenter1",region="region1"} 0.0

vmware_cluster_currentFailoverLevel{cluster_name="cluster3",dc_name="datacenter2",region="region2"} 0.0
```

In my example, cluster1 and cluster2 are in the region1 and cluster3 in the region2.
Each hypervisor have a cluster_name label value.
Each cluster have a region label value.

I would like get the sum value of vmware_host_num_cpu for all clusters in the same region based on the cluster_name of each hypervisor and the region label of cluster.

In my example, result should be :

```
Total num_cpu for region1 = 14.0
Total num_cpu for region2 = 2.0
```

Do you have an idea on how do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum by (region) (
     vmware_host_num_cpu 
  + on(cluster_name) group_left(region) 
    vmware_cluster_currentFailoverLevel * 0
)
```

It'd be cleaner if there was an info metric to do the join on.